# Error in instantiating servlet class in intelliJ idea

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, boilerpipe

i'm using intellij for developing my web application using boilerpipe jar to create an application like [this](https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/),but i'm getting error in instantiating servlet class ..
this is my servlet code

```
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.BoilerpipeProcessingException;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private final static Logger LOGGER  = Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName());



    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        try {

            String urlString = "http://commercialobserver.com/2014/06/50102-sf-mixed-use-building-planned-for-east-harlem/";
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            String article = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
            writer.println(article);
            LOGGER.info("Content extracted successfully ");
            writer.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            LOGGER.severe("Exception thrown for invalid url " + e);
        } catch (BoilerpipeProcessingException e) {
            LOGGER.severe("Exception thrown during scraping process " + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.severe("Exception thrown" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i'm getting classnotfound exception ...on boilerpipe ...it fails to find boilerpipe class ...i'm sure that i have added it in the dependeny and updated the .iml file